# Trouble with connecting to Git Server via Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, git-clone

Friends, i keep getting the following error in Jenkins console.

```
"Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h ssh://yyyyyyyy@gerrit.xxxxxxxx.com:29418/mobile HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

Tried all the options on the web. Nothing worked. 
Appreciate your help here

Complete Log Here

```
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/GIT
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository ssh://yyyyy@gerrit.xxxxxxxx.com:29418/mobile
 > git init /Users/Shared/Jenkins/GIT # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://yyyyy@gerrit.xxxxxxxx.com:29418/mobile
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://yyyyyyy@gerrit.xxxxxxxxx.com:29418/mobile +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://yyyyyy@gerrit.xxxxxxxxx.com:29418/mobile +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thanks,
Madhav

Comment: I did create .ssh folder and was able to connect to GIT via command prompt (Terminal). i use OS X BTW

Comment: Are you able to clone the repo on your local system without jenkins using ssh?

Comment: Absolutely. it does. But some times i do have to run this command /n ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa /n to make the clone command work Only problem via Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a permissions problem on your .ssh folder or your id_rsa* files.

Please have a look to this article to set the correct permissions:
https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder

The .ssh folder should exist in the home folder of your jenkins user (something like /home/jenkins or /var/lib/jenkins).

The permissions should be:

- .ssh folder: 700 (drwx------)
- public key (.pub): 644 (-rw-r--r--)
- private key (id_rsa): 600 (-rw-------)

Please confirm it fixed your issue :)

Comment: Thanks Bruno. but the permissions are set to 777 which is like full access. Still the same problem Madhav-iMAC:Madhav administrator$  ls -l .ssh/
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jenkins  staff  3326 May 12 18:44 id_rsa
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jenkins  staff   763 May 12 18:44 id_rsa.pub

Comment: Also, how does Jenkins know where the .ssh folder is located ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You have to use the exact permissions on the .ssh folder and the id_rsa* files. Otherwise, your key will not be recognised.

Comment: I made the changes. still the same issue. Will keep trying. Thanks

Comment: What is your git repository manager? Gihub? Or a hosted solution like Atlassian Bitbucket?

Comment: Gerrit hosted on our internal servers

Comment: I had the same issue with our Bitbucket server (hosted internally). Every time, it was a permission problem on the .ssh folder/files.

Comment: Also check the known_hosts file